# Encoding in resources

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding

I like to create an HTML file in code.

For that I created the HTML file in question from scratch in a text editor, exchanged the variable part of this file with a placeholder and saved this file as txt file. The text editor is telling me, that the file is a "UTF-8 without BOM" file.

I added this text file as a file resource to my project, and used it like that:

```
Dim result as StringBuilder

result = New StringBuilder
result.AppendLine(My.Resources.Template)
result.Replace("<PlaceHolder>", "Content")

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("<file name>", result.ToString, False, Encoding.UTF8)
```

So, all in all I have a UTF-8 file, add this file to a `StringBuilder` and save this new file as UTF-8 file.

Nonetheless, in the new saved file some special characters who look fine in my source file are scrambled.

What did I miss? Where is my problem with the encoding?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Set a breakpoint at the last line and see if the content of the `result.ToString()` has those special characters displayed correctly or not.

Comment: Not so clear how this went wrong.  But when the .txt file does not have a BOM then VS has to guess at the encoding when you add the resource.   You don't like what it guessed at, Encoding.Default is not Encoding.UTF8.  Don't force it to guess, use Project > Add New Item > General > Text File and it will be saved with a BOM.

Comment: Looks like Notepad++ is better in guessing the encoding of a file than Microsoft. After saving my file resource as UTF-8 (with BOM) all problems went away. If you change your comment to an answer I could upvote it.